# Sqlite Performance When Deleting Table Data

Tags: performance, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a method that deletes all of the records in my local sqlite database.

```
public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}
```

I noticed that if I have about 400+ records (simple rows with about 5 string columns each)to delete it takes about 2 seconds and freezes up my UI. However, if I have anywhere under 100 records it works almost instantly. What I want to know is whether this is normal or if I probably have some code lurking somewhere that is causing performance issues. I'm a beginner, so it wouldn't shock me in the slightest to find out I have some very ugly code locking everything up.

Comment: Each delete becomes a separate transaction, bracketed by start/commit, and accompanied by writing the transaction journal.  Just as with inserts you should do all deletes in a group within a single transaction -- you'll see about a 100x performance improvement.

Comment: Only pull what data you need when you need it (in general) from the database to your client is where you are going wrong. Delete everything from a table is an action where you don't need any data in the table, so follow juergen d's advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all records in a table then simply call a single query

```
truncate your_table
```

or

```
delete from your_table
```

Try to avoid calling queries all the time which is slow. Rather try to process the data with a single query.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a `truncate` command, but `DELETE FROM table` without a `WHERE` clause accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Thanks!